# Stop a page from refreshing after firing a function

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I've been tasked with building a very simple app that that has a series of dropdowns in rows of 2, when 2 are selected, a simple functions concatenates the 2 values and gives an output next to them like so:

`dropdown1 dropdown2 Output`

What I'm trying to get is, once the second dropdown value is chosen the function runs and displays the output where it says `output`. But currently, what seems to happens is the output is displayed in a new window.

Here's what I have so far (HTML):

```
<form>
<select id="test">
<option>Arena/Quantum Barcelona LTBC</option>
<option>Arena/Quantum Spain LTES</option>
</select>

<select id="name" onchange="tryThis()">
<option>Name</option>
<option>Name1</option>
</select>

</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function tryThis() {

var string, string1 = '';

var e = document.getElementById("test");
string = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

var a = document.getElementById("name");
string1 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;
document.write(string+'_'+string1);
}
```

Am I making this more difficult than it needs to be?!

Comment: Either create a new element or set the content of an existing element; `document.write` will wipe out your page. And I'd recommend using a JS library to make all that easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `document.write` clears the page before displaying something. You should never need to use that function.

Instead, you could append it to e.g. the body:

```
document.body.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(string + '_' + string2)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed that your JS function is called `tryThis()` and on the event handler you're calling `tryThsis()`

However in your case I'd refrain from using `document.write`, good alternatives are appending to the body or having a DIV and changing the `innerHTML` of that DIV

Comment: Yeah sorry I realised, that was just me being dumb but I've correct this now :)

Answer (score 0):

First put an id on your form so that it is easier to access.

```
var a = (function () {
    var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm"),
        magic = function () {
            var a = myForm.getElementsByTagName("select"),
                b,
                c = [];
            for (b = a.length - 1; b > -1; b -= 1) {
                c.push(a[b].value);
            }
            alert(c.join(" ") + " output");
        };
    myForm.onclick = magic;
}());
```

You were not specific as to what the extra "output" is supposed to be or how you want the data returned, but here you go.  Instead of using an alert you could push the result into the value of a different form element.  Do not use `document.write` as this cannot be deferred.  If you attempt to defer a document.write operation it will replace the entirety of the body contents of the current page.